# Special name for two variables that sum to one?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, convention

I'm curious if there is any special name for the variables in the following function:

$\alpha+\beta=1$,

such that each can be determined by subtracting 1 from the other. Sort of like saying $\alpha$ is the 'reciprocal' of $\beta$ ...but through subtraction by 1 instead of division by 1.

Comment: They are complimentary of each other.

Answer (score 4):

We might say that $\beta$ is the *complement* of $\alpha$ in $1$ and vice versa.